# Conversão de character em Date - 4 dígitos

Tags: r

Estou tendo dificuldade ao usar o as.Date para converter uma coluna com datas (ano com só dois caracteres) em data.
O as.Date autocompleta o ano de forma errada, produzindo resultados como 2066( ao invés de 1966)

```
    > head(data_de_nascimento)
    [1] "16/03/66" "11/06/87" "21/11/75" "05/09/70" "15/08/70" "15/08/70"
    > str(data_de_nascimento)
    chr [1:4245] "16/03/66" "11/06/87" "21/11/75" "05/09/70" "15/08/70" ...
    > data_de_nascimento_format <- as.Date(data_de_nascimento,
    + format = "%d/%m/%y" )
    > head(data_de_nascimento_format)
    [1] "2066-03-16" "1987-06-11" "1975-11-21" "1970-09-05" "1970-08-15"
```

Answer (score 5):

Essa é uma regra estranha de inferência de século na máscara de ano `y`.

Na [documentação](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) temos a seguinte informação sobre a conversão de datas com dois dígitos:

> `%y` Ano sem século (00–99). Na entrada, valores entre 00 e 68 são
>   prefixados por 20 e valores entre 69 e 99 por 19 – esse é o comportamento
>   especificado pelas normas POSIX 2004 e 2008, porém eles [os autores da 
>   norma] também dizem que "é
>   esperado que em uma versão futura o século padrão inferido de uma ano de dois 
>   dígitos irá mudar".

Dessa forma, cabe a aplicação manipular o século conforme suas próprias regras, por exemplo, você pode fixar que datas no futuro devem ser convertidas para o século 20:

```
data_de_nascimento = c("16/03/66", "11/06/87", "21/11/75", "05/09/70", 
                       "15/08/70", "15/08/70")
d <- as.Date(data_de_nascimento, "%d/%m/%y" )  
data_de_nascimento_format <- as.Date(
     ifelse(d > Sys.Date(), format(d, "19%y-%m-%d"), format(d)))
```

Você pode substituir `Sys.Date()` por uma data de corte específica. Por exemplo, se quiser que penas datas entre 00 e 10 sejam inferidas para o século 21 use `"2010-12-31"`. Nesse caso, `16/03/10` será interpretado como `"2010-03-16"`, porém `16/03/11` será interpretado como `"1911-03-16"`.

#### [Veja funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/PyO0XQ)

---

**Referência:** [SOen - Add correct century to dates with year provided as “Year without century”, %y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508747/664577)